# How to combine Redis commands 'expire' and 'sadd' into one command?

Tags: redis

I need to create a set in Redis:

```
redis> SADD myset "Hello"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD myset "World"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD myset "World"
(integer) 0
redis> SMEMBERS myset
1) "World"
2) "Hello"
```

But I need to set expire time for the key `myset`.

In other words I need a command kind of `expire sadd myset...` (like SETEX for string values).

Is there any way to execute these commands per one request to Redis server?

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in command to do this. What you may do is; using transactions. As it is stated in the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/transactions);

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a single isolated operation.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD mynewset a b c d e f g
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD mynewset f g h j k l
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIRE mynewset 86400
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> EXEC
1) (integer) 7
2) (integer) 4
3) (integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL mynewset
(integer) 86394
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Transactions have one drawback though that is easy to overlook and create a mess. If your code relies on a single shared redis connection (which is recommended), then you call MULTI from one place, but another user/request can start putting commands in there.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the possibility of using a Lua script to tie the two commands together:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "redis.call('SADD', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV)) redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], 3600)" 1 myset a b c d e
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS myset
1) "c"
2) "d"
3) "a"
4) "b"
5) "e"
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL myset
(integer) 3596
```